# redis-server exited with status code 1

Tags: redis, gruntjs

I have a gruntfile and I open a redis-server using external daemon:

```
 external_daemon: {
        redis: {
            cmd: 'redis-server',
            args: ['--port', '6380',
                   '--requirepass', 'S3CR3T',
                   '--loglevel', 'notice',
                   '--logfile', 'stdout']
        }
    },
```

I want to use the redis server as a session store 
It does say: started redis but my webpage is showing errors because I don't have the right redis-server

Comment: What is the setup for redis inside your app? Do you have the same port and password setup? Grunt will only setup and run an external task but won't setup the client inside your application to interface with that task, in this case, redis.

Comment: I work in a group and it works for them :/ I tried changing the port